# GPU on apply function colab

Tags: python, cuda, gpu, google-colaboratory, stanford-nlp

I use this apply function on my code:

```
def entities_extraction(text):
    doc = nlp(text)
    entities= [ent.text for sentence in doc.sentences for ent in sentence.entities if ent.type in {"PERSON", "ORG", "GPE", "NORP", "FAC", "LOC", "PRODUCT", "EVENT", "WORK_OF_ART", "LAW", "LANGUAGE", "MISC"}]
    return entities

df["entities"] = df['text'].progress_apply(lambda x: entities_extraction(x))
```

The problem is that, at the moment, it is too slow (it take nearly 12 hours)

So I tried to modify it to use colab gpu:

```
@cuda.jit
def entities_extraction(text):
    doc = nlp(text)
    entities= [ent.text for sentence in doc.sentences for ent in sentence.entities if ent.type in {"PERSON", "ORG", "GPE", "NORP", "FAC", "LOC", "PRODUCT", "EVENT", "WORK_OF_ART", "LAW", "LANGUAGE", "MISC"}]
    return entities
```

But I get this error:

```
ValueError: 
Kernel launch configuration was not specified. Use the syntax:

kernel_function[blockspergrid, threadsperblock](arg0, arg1, ..., argn)

See https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/cuda/kernels.html#kernel-invocation for help.
```

Do you know how to solve it, or you have a better implementation for gpu on apply functions?

Sorry if I made a lot of mistakes, I'm new to the argument of gpu for faster code.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is the nlp function taken from spaCy or else?

Comment: It is taken from Stanza

Comment: You can't use Numba cuda kernels for what you are trying to do. Nothing in that `entities_extraction` function is supported on the GPU

Answer (score 1):

You should write a code that cuda.jit decorator expects as shown in the [link](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/cuda/examples.html) or you could try to use [cuDF.apply](https://docs.rapids.ai/api/cudf/stable/api.html?highlight=apply#cudf.core.dataframe.DataFrame.apply). However, I am unsure if the cuDF supports for your function in lambda.

Alternatively, you could use Stanza [Pipeline API](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/pipeline.html) with `use_gpu=True` parameter. See the basic example section, and you should pay attention to the note in there.

Comment: The problem is that cuDF is not available in colab, when I try to install it gives me this error: ERROR: Failed building wheel for cudf, Failed to build cudf

Comment: @Radix I think that instead of building the cuDF in the Google Colab, you could use the Stanza Pipeline.